# Stack and linkedlist implementation

Tags: java, stack, queue

I'm having issues at the query section.

For an example I add `1 2 3 4 5` in the stack. If i were to query 4, this program is supposed to remove 1 2 and 3. Thus leaving behind 4 and 5.

But I received an error:

```
java.util.InputMismatchExceptionat  while(!
(Integer.valueOf(sc.nextInt()).equals(stack.peek())) && !(stack.isEmpty()))
```

**This is my code:**

```
public class StackExercise {
   public static void main(String [] args) throws NoSuchElementException {

      StackLL <Integer> stack = new StackLL <Integer> ();
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String op;

      while (sc.hasNext()) {
         op = sc.next();

         if (op.equals("add")) {
            // Fill in the code 
            while(sc.hasNextInt()){
            stack.push(sc.nextInt());
         }
         sc.nextLine();
         }  else if (op.equals("query"))  {
            // Fill in the code 

            while(sc.hasNextInt()){
               while(!(Integer.valueOf(sc.nextInt()).equals(stack.peek())) && !(stack.isEmpty())){
                  stack.pop();
               }
            }
            sc.nextLine();
          }
         if(op.equals("add")){
            if(stack.isEmpty()){}
            else
               System.out.println("Items added: " +stack.toString());
         }  else if(op.equals("query"))  {
            if(stack.isEmpty())
               System.out.println("Query not met: " +stack.toString());
            else
               System.out.println("Query met: " +stack.toString());
         }
      }
   }
      // You may write additional method(s) to make your program more modular
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, you're not actually implementing either a stack or a linked-list here. Also typically you don't 'query' a stack, you pop from it. If you can 'query' it, it's just an array/linked list.

Comment: it's just an exanple of using stack and linkedlist

Comment: this is the line " while(!(Integer.valueOf(sc.nextInt()).equals(stack.peek())) && !(stack.isEmpty()))" that is a problem but i don't know how to solve it